# When I killed tty1 root user on ubuntu14.04，the system reboot. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, tty, kill, reboot

When I enter `who` command in the shell, i got this:

```
root         tty1   2017-04-01 12:21
langxiaowei  pts/2  2017-07-21 18:05
```

So, for the safe, I want to kill the root user. Then I enter the comamnd in the shell:

```
sudo pkill -kill -t tty1
```

After, I enter who command again, I sure the root user is gone! But, a few seconds later, I lost connection from the machine. The host is not alive. The host restarted.
I saw the `last -x` output, it's below:

```
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.13.0-24-generi Fri Jul 21 18:10 - 00:45  (06:35)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-24-generi Fri Jul 21 18:10 - 00:45  (06:35)    
shutdown system down  3.13.0-24-generi Fri Jul 21 18:06 - 18:10  (00:03)    
langxiao pts/2        10.15.1.15       Fri Jul 21 18:05 - down   (00:00)
```

The syslog output is :

```
Jul 21 18:06:39 ubuntu kernel: [9611571.765277] init: mountall-shell main process (6462) killed by KILL signal

Jul 21 18:06:40 ubuntu kernel: [9611571.879372] init: tty1 main process (1221) killed by HUP signal

Jul 21 18:06:40 ubuntu kernel: [9611571.879387] init: tty1 main process ended, respawning
```

The Linux Version is : `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS \n \l`

The kernel is : `Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I seemly `ps -ef|grep tty1`, saw `/sbin/sulogin`, perhaps there has relations. As I knew the comamnd `pkill -kill -t tty1` is safe, can not cause reboot host. But why here reboot?

I connected the host from remote on the secureCRT.

PS:

On Host B, I alse do `pkill -kill -t tty1`, there is no reboot, and the syslog is :

```
Jul 21 18:04:34 ubuntu kernel: [32147390.433895] init: tty1 main process (997) killed by KILL signal

Jul 21 18:04:34 ubuntu kernel: [32147390.433917] init: tty1 main process ended, respawning
```